# Max load on analog output

Tags: analog, transmitter, plc

I am planning to connect an Omron ZL1-series 4-20 mA level transmitter to a 0-10V input on a PLC.
To do so, I have to convert the current to a measurable voltage by connecting a 500 Ω resistor to the PLC's input.

However, in the documentation for the LT This is stated:

> Analog output: Current output: 4 to 20 mA, maximum load resistance:
> 300 Ω (The output is 20 mA for the nearest point in the measurement
> range in respect to the Sensor and 4 mA for the farthest point.)

Does this mean I can't use it as a 0-10 V input?

[image]

Comment: Convert current to voltage... Yo need a transimpedance amplifier and if any of the answers suggest something else I am ready for upvote lol.

Comment: If the input ADC has enough bits for your requirements, it's fine to feed it 0-5V...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does this mean I can't use it as a 0-10 V input?*

Correct, unless adding a 2:1 gain non-inverting buffer after loading the 4/20 mA with (say) 250 Ω: -

[image]

Loading with 250 Ω means the output is 5 volts with an input current of 20 mA. I might add that 250 Ω is pretty standard for converting current outputs to voltage.

### Why transimpedance amplifiers (TIAs) not favoured for this task

- Well, a resistor is pretty simple and is as accurate as the resistor used as the feedback element in a TIA.
- 20 mA can be quite a lot for the op-amp in a TIA to deal with and there are going to be problems with several common op-amps because of this.
- Some 4/20 mA devices are specified to run into a minimum load when powered from higher loop voltages - driving a resistor at 20 mA (and losing 5 volts) means that the 4/20 mA device has a lower terminal voltage across it and dissipates less power. In other words, it can be a problem using a TIA because it presents an input impedance of 0 Ω.
- A TIA absolutely requires a negative supply voltage - so this isn't a clear benefit at all.
- A TIA produces a negative output voltage and this is of no benefit unless you are prepared to add another inverting stage afterwards (and your error budget might be falling apart by now).

Comment: Andy have you seen my comment? No upvote for you. Lmao.

Comment: I saw your "comment" but why should that stop me posting an accurate answer?

Comment: Funny how you put the comment in quotes. To remind you had posted a similar comment before this question was posted.

Comment: @Se1fie please do link me to that earlier comment and please also note the words I've added to my answer about using a TIA.

Comment: @Bakkom I'd need to double check the data sheet so can you provide a link to it please?

Comment: @Andyaka https://assets.omron.eu/downloads/datasheet/en/v5/e416_zx1_smart_laser_sensor_with_built-in_amplifier_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: You've deleted your comment that caused me to ask for the data sheet and I can't remember what you asked @Bakkom

Comment: @Andyaka Oh, sorry. I was confused by the "Max residual voltage" because I thought it was the total voltage output, but I can see I have some reading to do.

Answer (score -2):

You need a transimpedance amplifier. You can put variable resistor in the place of the feedback resistor to get any value of voltage you want.